# Why is triangle law so important in Data Mining

Tags: data-mining

I am interested in knowing why triangle law is so important for a better data mining.As far as I know the triangle law helps us to define patterns and form clusters based on the distances between different objects.Does anyone have any other inputs for triangle law?

Comment: You may want to look at this for some help: http://www.slidefinder.net/g/graph_mining_patterns_generators_tools/faloutsos_graphmining/21274124/p2

Comment: This should be on stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not that important. In data mining, we cannot generally assume to have a proper "mathematical" distance function. As soon as we allow duplicates, we already lose one of the key axioms - we *can* have two different objects with the distance 0. (And in classification, they may even have different classes in the worst case).

However, the triangle inequality can allow us to *prune* the search space. If we have a distance function that satisfies triangle inequality and use an appropriate index, we can **skip a lot of computations**, thus making the algorithm faster.

Note that a lot of research and implementations do not so much care about this kind of optimization. Many data miners working with R like building a distance matrix (which is in `O(n^2)`!) and then try to do as much as possible with matrix operations, because that is simple to program and R is quite fast at this kind of operations (using a highly optimized C code, instead of interpreted R code). But if you need to go beyond this, a key ingredient for performance is to exploit triangle inequality where possible.